# Problem with configuring hmailServer

Tags: java, smtp, hmail-server

I am writing a program using java to send e mail. I notice that, the java program executes successfully, but the email is not reaching the intended recipients. I am using hMailServer as my SMTP server.

The server runs on port 25. I have confirmed that the firewall allows this port.

I ran a diagnostic test on the hMailServer and got the following report.

[image]

Also, I found that emails got queued in the server.

```
 Return-Path: <>
Message-ID: <C49CD35F-1204-4E7A-B520-18371344CC5C@localhost>
Date: Tue, 2 Aug 2011 16:50:04 +0530
From: mailer-daemon@localhost
 To: user2@test.com
Subject: Undeliverable: Hi
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
  X-hMailServer-LoopCount: 1

Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

    Sent: Tue, 2 Aug 2011 16:50:01 +0530 (IST)
     Subject: Hi

     The following recipient(s) could not be reached:

      myname@gmail.com
      Error Type: SMTP
      Error Description: No mail servers appear to exists for the 
      recipients address.Additional information: Please check
      that you have not misspelled the recipients  email address.
```

What might be the issue. Can you help fix this issue?

Comment: are you able to connect using outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the domain `test.com` you want your domain to be local. Try something like `test.local`